# Primefaces SelectManyMenu with Filter: How to select all displayed Items with JS

Tags: javascript, ajax, primefaces

I have SelectManyMenu (primeFaces 6.1) and "Select All" and "Deselect All" buttons, which selects/deselects all items in the selection list.I modified the SelectManyMenu with a filter,but my "Select All" button still relies on the java method for selection, which means all items of the **unfiltered** (complete) selection list appears selected even user filters the selection list before clicking "Select All".
Is there a way to select all displayed (filtered or unfiltered) items in SelectmanyMenu on client side?
I tried to make a "Select All item on Filtered List" button which is rendered conditionally (if user types into Filter box)  but i can't find any events that i can use in order to create a filter-based action.

#### *xhtml File:*

```
     <h:panelGroup id="param-type-3-cell-2" layout="block">
                    <p:selectManyMenu id="selectManyMenu" 
                                      rendered="#{parameter.multiValue}"
                                      value="#{parameter.selectionList.selectionLabelListString}"
                                      disabled="#{parameter.ruleParam.option ne 'OPTION_DEFAULT' or parameter.readonly or not parameter.fullyLoaded}"
                                      label="#{parameter.selectedLabel}"
                                      style="width:#{parameter.selectionList.listWidth}px;"
                                      styleClass="sb-input-small" scrollHeight="#{parameter.selectionList.listStyleHeightMaxInt}"
                                      filter="#{parameter.listBoxFilter}" filterMatchMode="#{parameter.listBoxFilterMode}">
                        <f:selectItems value="#{parameter.selectionList.selectionList}" 
                                       var="selitem" 
                                       itemValue="#{selitem.label}" 
                                       itemLabel="#{selitem.label}" />
                        <!-- AJAX if this param acts as a trigger for other params -->
                        <p:ajax event="change"
                                listener="#{myController.handleParameters(parameter)}"
                                oncomplete="parameterChangeAction()"
                                disabled="#{empty parameter.listOfTriggeredParameters}"/>

                    </p:selectManyMenu>

                    <h:panelGroup layout="block">
                        <h:outputText id="numberOfValues"
                                      value="#{msg.param_show_entries} #{parameter.selectionList.numberOfSelectedValues}"
                                      style="#{parameter.readonly or not parameter.fullyLoaded ? 'opacity: 0.3;' : ''}"/>
                    </h:panelGroup>

                    <h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="paramButtonPanel">
                        <p:commandButton rendered="#{parameter.multiValue}"
                                         disabled="#{parameter.readonly or not parameter.fullyLoaded}"
                                         styleClass="rich-button-submit inline-block" 
                                         value="#{msg.param_button_all}"
                                         oncomplete="parameterChangeAction()"
                                         process="@this"
                                         widgetVar="BtnSaveAll"
                                         id="selectAllBtn"
                                         action="#{parameter.selectionList.selectAll}"
                                         title="#{msg.param_button_allhint}" >
                            <!-- AJAX if this param acts as a trigger for other params -->
                            <p:ajax event="click"
                                    listener="#{myController.handleParameters(parameter)}"
                                    disabled="#{empty parameter.listOfTriggeredParameters}"/>
                        </p:commandButton>

                        <p:commandButton rendered="#{parameter.multiValue}"
                                         disabled="#{parameter.readonly or not parameter.fullyLoaded}"
                                         styleClass="rich-button-submit inline-block" 
                                         style="margin-left: 5px;"
                                         value="#{msg.param_button_nothing}"
                                         oncomplete="parameterChangeAction()"
                                         id="deselectAllBtn"
                                         process="@this"
                                         action="#{parameter.selectionList.deselectAll}"
                                         title="#{msg.param_button_nothinghint}" >
                            <p:ajax event="click"
                                    listener="#{myController.handleParameters(parameter)}"
                                    disabled="#{empty parameter.listOfTriggeredParameters}"/>
                        </p:commandButton>
                    </h:panelGroup>
                </h:panelGroup>
```

#### *Parameter object:*

```
    /**
     *
     * @return
     */
    public BirdSelectionList getSelectionList()
    {
        return selectionList;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param selectionList
     */
    public void setSelectionList(MySelectionList selectionList)
    {
        this.selectionList = selectionList;
    }
```

#### *MySelectionList object:*

```
    public void selectAll()
    {
        selectionListString = new ArrayList<>();
        for (MySelectItem selectItem : selectionList)
        {
            selectionListString.add(selectItem.getValue());
        }
    }
    public void deselectAll()
    {
        this.selectionListString = new ArrayList<>();
    }
```

Has anyone an idea how this can be done?

P.S : I use PrimeFaces 6.1

Answer (score 1):

You can add a javascript method to the SelectManyMenu widget selecting only visible items:

```
PrimeFaces.widget.SelectManyMenu.prototype.selectVisible =  function() {
        for(var i = 0; i < this.items.length; i++) {
            var item = this.items.eq(i);
            if(item.is(':visible')) {
                this.selectItem(item);
            } else {
                this.unselectItem(item);
            }
        }
    };
```

Then on your button simply trigger a `PF('yourSelectManyMenuWidgetVar').selectVisible()`.

The code is borrowed and modified from the [selectAll method](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/pull/2896/commits/b27ac35dd1477ab7bcd8dd497560ca2bdd180ed0#diff-1ffcfe70ad3198ae2ac133f04e5ec20a). Make sure above modification is loaded **after** primefaces scripts.

Also make sure to propose a feature request like [isse 2895](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/2895) to the primefaces team - enriched with a pull request in best case.

Comment: Good answer... Effectively it is all html, javascript (with the help of jquery) and the open source of PrimeFaces... All just web development really... ;-)